Nuxt Vue display component based on parameter/type
I am fairly new to Nuxt and Vuejs. I have googled for a solution but haven't found any.
I have a page with component <VTextField></VTextField> and <VSwitch></VSwitch>, sample code of the page is as below
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
</script>
<template>
    <VTextField></VTextField>
    <VSwitch></VSwitch>
</template>

But instead of directly using the component, I have a requirement that needs to be followed where I have an API that will provide me with the "type" and based on the "type" value will display the component.
I tried creating a function for this and the code is as below.
utils/RenderComponent.ts:
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { VTextField } from 'vuetify/components';
import { VSwitch } from 'vuetify/components';

export function renderComponent(type: any) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'Text':
            return defineComponent({
                components: { VTextField },
                template: '<VTextField/>'
            });
        case 'switch':
            return defineComponent({
                components: { VSwitch },
                template: '<VSwitch/>'
            });
        default:
            throw new Error('Invalid component type');
    }
}

Page.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { renderComponent } from '~/utils/RenderComponent';
</script>
<template>
    <component :is="renderComponent('Text')" />

    <component :is="renderComponent('Switch')" />
</template>

But the code does not work. What can I try next?

I dont see any reason to create a custom component here. You should be able to directly return the vuetify components in your switch-case

you can use a conditional directly in template
<script setup lang="ts">
 import { ref } from 'vue';
 const componentType = ref('switch')
</script>
<template>
 <VTextField v-if="componentType === 'switch"></VTextField>
 <VSwitch v-else-if="componentType === 'textfield'"></VSwitch>
....
</template>


but it is not only for text and switch, and there are also multiple other pages that requires this function.
